# Adding universe:utilities in my app breaks it

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using `accounts-password`, Universe Audio Recorder packages. Universe Audio Recorder has dependency on `universe:utilities` and when I add it, the Meteor build fails.

Log:

```
meteor
[[[[[ ~/meteor/test ]]]]]                     

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
I20151003-14:33:37.955(5.5)? ======== Universe Audio Recorder ========
I20151003-14:33:37.957(5.5)? sox:      SoX v14.4.1
W20151003-14:33:37.957(5.5)? (STDERR) 
    W20151003-14:33:37.957(5.5)? (STDERR) /home/ajit/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.ltydx3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
    W20151003-14:33:37.958(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
    W20151003-14:33:37.958(5.5)? (STDERR)                             ^
    W20151003-14:33:38.026(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: A method named '/universe_configs/insert' is already defined
    W20151003-14:33:38.026(5.5)? (STDERR)     at livedata_server.js:1536:15
    W20151003-14:33:38.026(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
    W20151003-14:33:38.026(5.5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (livedata_server.js:1532:7)
    W20151003-14:33:38.027(5.5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:923:1)
    W20151003-14:33:38.027(5.5)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:214:1)
    W20151003-14:33:38.027(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/universe_utilities/UniConfig.js:3:1)
    W20151003-14:33:38.027(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/ajit/meteor/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/universe_utilities.js:642:4
    W20151003-14:33:38.027(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/ajit/meteor/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/universe_utilities.js:652:3
    W20151003-14:33:38.027(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/ajit/meteor/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
    W20151003-14:33:38.027(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
```

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please remember to post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning!

Comment: the error is explaining it perfectly we cannot remotely check your files unfortunately to figure out where you have a duplicated method :)